# How can i push a form to the right on big screens and put in the middle on small screens

Tags: html

I want my search bar to be position on the right of the screen on big screens while it should be in the center on small screens

The form is a bootstrap 4 form,
This is code for the navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark navbar-inverse bg-dark justify-content-between fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand d-none d-sm-block text-white">Daking</a>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 ">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">      
        </form>
    </nav>
```

I used media query for small screens:

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  form {
    width: 100% ; 
    position: relative;
}
}
```

But on large screens(desktop), it positions it close to the brand name(daking)

Comment: use `pull-right` class on your input, which helps to float right.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
  form {
        width: auto;
    position: relative;
    float: right;

  }
}
```